# Log link vs logging response variable in GAM model

Tags: r-squared, gamma-distribution, generalized-additive-model, residuals, link-function

My aim is to build a value predictor of an individual’s pension pot using customer data (based in the UK).  It is to be used for reporting purposes and prioritising/targeting customers. Data is:

- Current pension size (size) [RESPONSE VARIABLE]
- Age (age)
- Year Employment started (yrstart)
- Year Employment ended (yrend)
- Duration of employment (yrstart-yrend)
- Gender (gen)
- UK postcode prefix (post)

I am using GAM models for the analysis.

**My main question is, in this case, should I opt for logging the response variable rather than using a log link function? The diagnostics seem to be healthier with the logged response variable (ie R-squared and residual/fitted plots).**

Further question: Does the large number of postcode prefix dummy variables present a problem?

Any further tips or advice on how to make the predictor is much appreciated ☺ I’m happy to provide more information on the analysis or dataset if required.

Let me define the two potential models:

```r
m1 <- gam(log(size) ~ s(age) + s(dur) + s(yrend) + 
          s(yrstart) + gen + post,     family=Gamma)

Family: Gamma 
Link function: inverse 

Formula:
log(size) ~ s(age) + s(dur) + s(yrend) + s(yrstart) + gen + post

Parametric coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.0818475  0.0152751   5.358 8.97e-08 ***
genFemale    0.0228772  0.0118520   1.930 0.053661 .  
genMale      0.0199456  0.0118453   1.684 0.092305 .  
postAB       0.0127508  0.0129126   0.987 0.323483    
postAL       0.0067097  0.0102094   0.657 0.511089    
postB        0.0216764  0.0100494   2.157 0.031077 *  
postBA       0.0200071  0.0108573   1.843 0.065457 .  
postBB       0.1106482  0.0192486   5.748 9.82e-09 ***
postBD       0.0139438  0.0114125   1.222 0.221868    
postBH       0.0276829  0.0113779   2.433 0.015025 *  
postBL       0.0092992  0.0107245   0.867 0.385950    
postBN       0.0211968  0.0101299   2.093 0.036469 *  
postBR       0.0082556  0.0099079   0.833 0.404773    
postBS       0.0162293  0.0101521   1.599 0.110000    
postBT       0.0193330  0.0102182   1.892 0.058574 .  
postCA       0.0477834  0.0171535   2.786 0.005372 ** 
postCB       0.0094952  0.0104462   0.909 0.363437    
postCF       0.0192786  0.0099438   1.939 0.052616 .  
postCH       0.0202025  0.0102175   1.977 0.048095 *  
postCM       0.0189188  0.0100972   1.874 0.061062 .  
postCO       0.0332293  0.0110749   3.000 0.002716 ** 
postCR       0.0070088  0.0102735   0.682 0.495145    
postCT       0.0178006  0.0123764   1.438 0.150451    
postCV       0.0203044  0.0101370   2.003 0.045257 *  
postCW       0.0160363  0.0112470   1.426 0.154014    
postDA       0.0144510  0.0107019   1.350 0.177004    
postDD       0.0085950  0.0111744   0.769 0.441849    
postDE       0.0376456  0.0109537   3.437 0.000596 ***
postDG       0.0233830  0.0133539   1.751 0.080033 .  
postDH       0.0240970  0.0137649   1.751 0.080104 .  
postDL       0.0176673  0.0116697   1.514 0.130135    
postDT       0.0263172  0.0110110   2.390 0.016899 *  
postDY       0.0136146  0.0132202   1.030 0.303164    
postE        0.0129305  0.0097974   1.320 0.186992    
postEC       0.0076279  0.0105539   0.723 0.469880    
postEH       0.0150067  0.0099845   1.503 0.132932    
postEN       0.0225112  0.0123307   1.826 0.067997 .  
postEX       0.0273954  0.0106906   2.563 0.010434 *  
postFK       0.0684517  0.0232998   2.938 0.003327 ** 
postFL       0.0047612  0.0141676   0.336 0.736845    
postFY       0.1017214  0.0248667   4.091 4.40e-05 ***
postG        0.0196529  0.0100870   1.948 0.051459 .  
postGL       0.0283408  0.0103974   2.726 0.006449 ** 
postGU       0.0034250  0.0099715   0.343 0.731257    
postHA       0.0035290  0.0104726   0.337 0.736159    
postHD       0.0216910  0.0135712   1.598 0.110067    
postHG       0.0036120  0.0110516   0.327 0.743820    
postHP       0.0094661  0.0099645   0.950 0.342190    
postHR       0.0569993  0.0145099   3.928 8.73e-05 ***
postHU       0.0396125  0.0135897   2.915 0.003582 ** 
postHX       0.0138288  0.0144650   0.956 0.339132    
postIG       0.0096179  0.0104447   0.921 0.357202    
postIP       0.0318191  0.0107741   2.953 0.003166 ** 
postIV       0.0391091  0.0203706   1.920 0.054958 .  
postKA       0.0194555  0.0123664   1.573 0.115753    
postKT       0.0087211  0.0098956   0.881 0.378211    
postKY       0.0162673  0.0122258   1.331 0.183421    
postL        0.0198358  0.0105732   1.876 0.060736 .  
postLA       0.0519214  0.0186295   2.787 0.005349 ** 
postLE       0.0238333  0.0102484   2.326 0.020101 *  
postLL       0.0352446  0.0116572   3.023 0.002518 ** 
postLN       0.0387299  0.0155990   2.483 0.013082 *  
postLS       0.0229613  0.0099316   2.312 0.020841 *  
postLU       0.0246282  0.0105769   2.328 0.019946 *  
postM        0.0140237  0.0099235   1.413 0.157697    
postME       0.0231557  0.0103209   2.244 0.024925 *  
postMK       0.0185453  0.0100866   1.839 0.066062 .  
postML       0.0336348  0.0116200   2.895 0.003822 ** 
postN        0.0108097  0.0098662   1.096 0.273322    
postNE       0.0226184  0.0099398   2.276 0.022936 *  
postNG       0.0213154  0.0102876   2.072 0.038345 *  
postNN       0.0191585  0.0099837   1.919 0.055072 .  
postNP       0.0287674  0.0103549   2.778 0.005497 ** 
postNR       0.0265959  0.0116718   2.279 0.022750 *  
postNW       0.0069509  0.0100315   0.693 0.488419    
postOL       0.0249991  0.0108473   2.305 0.021247 *  
postOX       0.0131841  0.0101286   1.302 0.193118    
postPA       0.0269139  0.0116498   2.310 0.020935 *  
postPE       0.0211914  0.0103268   2.052 0.040240 *  
postPH       0.0100691  0.0105830   0.951 0.341448    
postPL       0.0235270  0.0114389   2.057 0.039787 *  
postPO       0.0211361  0.0105561   2.002 0.045336 *  
postPR       0.0275111  0.0115222   2.388 0.017011 *  
postQLD      0.0226480  0.0160393   1.412 0.158033    
postRG       0.0133123  0.0098133   1.357 0.175014    
postRH       0.0136243  0.0100002   1.362 0.173163    
postRM       0.0139309  0.0110170   1.264 0.206143    
postS        0.0170813  0.0100671   1.697 0.089838 .  
postSA       0.0101352  0.0104209   0.973 0.330830    
postSE       0.0075188  0.0097816   0.769 0.442145    
postSG       0.0224996  0.0101357   2.220 0.026497 *  
postSK       0.0199349  0.0101855   1.957 0.050408 .  
postSL       0.0080980  0.0102583   0.789 0.429929    
postSM       0.0115330  0.0103378   1.116 0.264670    
postSN       0.0110686  0.0101552   1.090 0.275817    
postSO       0.0230123  0.0100230   2.296 0.021740 *  
postSP       0.0161813  0.0105617   1.532 0.125600    
postSR       0.0200469  0.0145091   1.382 0.167163    
postSS       0.0185094  0.0105427   1.756 0.079236 .  
postST       0.0119007  0.0105449   1.129 0.259157    
postSW       0.0065393  0.0097299   0.672 0.501581    
postSY       0.0080445  0.0107791   0.746 0.455535    
postTA       0.0348955  0.0122400   2.851 0.004386 ** 
postTF      -0.0004883  0.0116230  -0.042 0.966489    
postTN       0.0099027  0.0099812   0.992 0.321205    
postTQ       0.0097578  0.0121361   0.804 0.421436    
postTR       0.0267181  0.0117550   2.273 0.023094 *  
postTS       0.0389984  0.0118683   3.286 0.001027 ** 
postTW       0.0121615  0.0099354   1.224 0.221015    
postUB       0.0176834  0.0110858   1.595 0.110775    
postW        0.0053416  0.0097920   0.546 0.585442    
postWA       0.0150144  0.0100548   1.493 0.135464    
postWC      -0.0017122  0.0128755  -0.133 0.894216    
postWD       0.0116887  0.0105817   1.105 0.269407    
postWF       0.0461597  0.0139231   3.315 0.000925 ***
postWN       0.0070088  0.0129087   0.543 0.587198    
postWR       0.0297697  0.0109700   2.714 0.006687 ** 
postWS       0.0060471  0.0114459   0.528 0.597312    
postWV       0.0086872  0.0108631   0.800 0.423938    
postYO       0.0573133  0.0117706   4.869 1.17e-06 ***
postZE       0.0206844  0.0176943   1.169 0.242492    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
         edf Ref.df      F  p-value    
s(age)     7.132  8.073 33.954  < 2e-16 ***
s(dur)     7.219  8.030 25.023  < 2e-16 ***
s(yrend)   8.572  8.917  9.468 3.48e-14 ***
s(yrstart) 7.398  7.869  9.376 1.31e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Rank: 156/157
R-sq.(adj) =  0.457   Deviance explained = 41.1%
GCV = 0.034631  Scale est. = 0.026519  n = 3504
```

[image: M1 Residual/Fitted Plot]

```r
m2 <- gam(size ~ s(age) + (dur) + s(yrend) + s(yrstart) + 
        gen + post, family=Gamma(link='log'))

Family: Gamma 
Link function: log 

Formula:
size1 ~ s(age) + (dur) + s(yrend) + s(yrstart) + gen + post

Parametric coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  8.73614    1.00400   8.701  < 2e-16 ***
dur         -0.53683    0.09630  -5.574 2.68e-08 ***
genFemale   -0.54356    0.71982  -0.755 0.450220    
genMale     -0.32233    0.71952  -0.448 0.654196    
postAB      -1.01564    0.79315  -1.281 0.200454    
postAL      -0.65598    0.64320  -1.020 0.307861    
postB       -1.35592    0.62643  -2.165 0.030496 *  
postBA      -1.29094    0.66128  -1.952 0.050999 .  
postBB      -5.76745    0.79448  -7.259 4.81e-13 ***
postBD      -1.18023    0.68248  -1.729 0.083840 .  
postBH      -2.33085    0.66815  -3.489 0.000492 ***
postBL      -1.26389    0.67343  -1.877 0.060633 .  
postBN      -1.27986    0.62984  -2.032 0.042226 *  
postBR      -0.66595    0.62735  -1.062 0.288528    
postBS      -1.25546    0.63307  -1.983 0.047433 *  
postBT      -1.52445    0.63297  -2.408 0.016076 *  
postCA      -2.50011    0.79221  -3.156 0.001614 ** 
postCB      -0.74723    0.65549  -1.140 0.254389    
postCF      -1.48744    0.62207  -2.391 0.016852 *  
postCH      -1.26746    0.63397  -1.999 0.045662 *  
postCM      -1.36208    0.62868  -2.167 0.030339 *  
postCO      -1.72524    0.66110  -2.610 0.009103 ** 
postCR      -0.43660    0.64272  -0.679 0.496993    
postCT      -0.59276    0.73794  -0.803 0.421874    
postCV      -1.35911    0.63023  -2.157 0.031112 *  
postCW      -1.28606    0.67743  -1.898 0.057725 .  
postDA      -1.07486    0.66225  -1.623 0.104673    
postDD       0.35234    0.71012   0.496 0.619806    
postDE      -2.59957    0.65557  -3.965 7.48e-05 ***
postDG      -1.30729    0.79263  -1.649 0.099178 .  
postDH      -2.20222    0.79441  -2.772 0.005600 ** 
postDL      -0.70936    0.70991  -0.999 0.317758    
postDT      -1.99417    0.66080  -3.018 0.002565 ** 
postDY      -1.66098    0.73725  -2.253 0.024327 *  
postE       -0.84147    0.61630  -1.365 0.172233    
postEC      -0.58172    0.65610  -0.887 0.375339    
postEH      -1.10694    0.62429  -1.773 0.076301 .  
postEN      -2.32072    0.70923  -3.272 0.001078 ** 
postEX      -2.06137    0.65120  -3.166 0.001562 ** 
postFK      -4.31837    0.93935  -4.597 4.44e-06 ***
postFL      -0.10262    0.94299  -0.109 0.913349    
postFY      -5.56196    0.94485  -5.887 4.33e-09 ***
postG       -1.18867    0.62729  -1.895 0.058186 .  
postGL      -1.72991    0.63504  -2.724 0.006481 ** 
postGU      -0.05581    0.62852  -0.089 0.929247    
postHA      -0.60417    0.64959  -0.930 0.352402    
postHD      -2.16982    0.79355  -2.734 0.006284 ** 
postHG      -0.59192    0.68967  -0.858 0.390813    
postHP      -0.59293    0.62649  -0.946 0.343999    
postHR      -3.25194    0.73709  -4.412 1.06e-05 ***
postHU      -2.08390    0.71998  -2.894 0.003824 ** 
postHX      -1.20983    0.94895  -1.275 0.202429    
postIG      -0.70798    0.65156  -1.087 0.277293    
postIP      -2.16196    0.64753  -3.339 0.000851 ***
postIV      -3.13204    0.93968  -3.333 0.000868 ***
postKA      -1.88117    0.73839  -2.548 0.010889 *  
postKT      -0.75176    0.62257  -1.208 0.227320    
postKY      -1.27068    0.71991  -1.765 0.077647 .  
postL       -1.26186    0.64330  -1.962 0.049900 *  
postLA      -5.35962    0.94598  -5.666 1.59e-08 ***
postLE      -1.91198    0.63393  -3.016 0.002580 ** 
postLL      -2.30315    0.66771  -3.449 0.000569 ***
postLN      -2.75864    0.79283  -3.480 0.000509 ***
postLS      -1.57872    0.62093  -2.543 0.011051 *  
postLU      -1.63754    0.64893  -2.523 0.011666 *  
postM       -1.00196    0.62212  -1.611 0.107371    
postME      -1.31958    0.63499  -2.078 0.037773 *  
postMK      -1.37016    0.62718  -2.185 0.028984 *  
postML      -2.47631    0.67862  -3.649 0.000267 ***
postN       -0.72162    0.61990  -1.164 0.244466    
postNE      -1.39000    0.62085  -2.239 0.025231 *  
postNG      -1.40982    0.63381  -2.224 0.026190 *  
postNN      -1.21813    0.62267  -1.956 0.050512 .  
postNP      -1.63669    0.63595  -2.574 0.010107 *  
postNR      -1.65751    0.68804  -2.409 0.016049 *  
postNW      -0.42227    0.62921  -0.671 0.502191    
postOL      -1.87705    0.65316  -2.874 0.004081 ** 
postOX      -0.50753    0.63284  -0.802 0.422621    
postPA      -1.57850    0.68993  -2.288 0.022205 *  
postPE      -1.24609    0.63518  -1.962 0.049869 *  
postPH      -0.53942    0.66106  -0.816 0.414569    
postPL      -2.07035    0.69123  -2.995 0.002763 ** 
postPO      -1.14378    0.64435  -1.775 0.075974 .  
postPR      -1.85315    0.67782  -2.734 0.006290 ** 
postQLD     -2.03494    0.94954  -2.143 0.032178 *  
postRG      -0.87832    0.61768  -1.422 0.155126    
postRH      -0.85912    0.62696  -1.370 0.170685    
postRM      -1.23896    0.67781  -1.828 0.067655 .  
postS       -1.04821    0.62891  -1.667 0.095664 .  
postSA      -0.83812    0.65179  -1.286 0.198576    
postSE      -0.51048    0.61621  -0.828 0.407489    
postSG      -1.37906    0.63023  -2.188 0.028726 *  
postSK      -1.40984    0.63331  -2.226 0.026070 *  
postSL      -0.81483    0.63813  -1.277 0.201729    
postSM      -1.03677    0.64227  -1.614 0.106571    
postSN      -0.38015    0.63549  -0.598 0.549749    
postSO      -1.58302    0.62391  -2.537 0.011217 *  
postSP      -0.99059    0.65472  -1.513 0.130374    
postSR      -1.40093    0.84622  -1.656 0.097916 .  
postSS      -1.27229    0.64784  -1.964 0.049624 *  
postST      -0.45468    0.66209  -0.687 0.492295    
postSW      -0.48369    0.61391  -0.788 0.430815    
postSY       0.54636    0.67024   0.815 0.415034    
postTA      -2.21527    0.70875  -3.126 0.001790 ** 
postTF      -0.05580    0.74588  -0.075 0.940367    
postTN      -0.65489    0.62627  -1.046 0.295777    
postTQ      -0.41124    0.74031  -0.556 0.578589    
postTR      -2.41700    0.69968  -3.454 0.000558 ***
postTS      -2.46418    0.67702  -3.640 0.000277 ***
postTW      -0.71448    0.62405  -1.145 0.252327    
postUB      -1.51563    0.67810  -2.235 0.025476 *  
postW       -0.11265    0.61730  -0.182 0.855209    
postWA      -1.08829    0.63047  -1.726 0.084408 .  
postWC      -0.13281    0.79275  -0.168 0.866960    
postWD      -0.75621    0.65407  -1.156 0.247695    
postWF      -2.35700    0.73743  -3.196 0.001405 ** 
postWN      -0.43080    0.79188  -0.544 0.586462    
postWR      -0.98390    0.66186  -1.487 0.137223    
postWS      -0.66211    0.70860  -0.934 0.350169    
postWV      -0.52655    0.67727  -0.777 0.436944    
postYO      -3.00906    0.66905  -4.497 7.11e-06 ***
postZE      -1.88486    0.93867  -2.008 0.044722 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    Approximate significance of smooth terms:
             edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(age)     7.595  8.423 46.20  <2e-16 ***
s(yrend)   8.836  8.985 11.13  <2e-16 ***
s(yrstart) 7.647  7.951 37.36  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Rank: 148/149
R-sq.(adj) =  -0.303   Deviance explained = 47.3%
GCV = 1.2895  Scale est. = 1.0105    n = 3504
```

[image: M2 Residual/Fitted Plot]

Comment: 1. You probably want postcode as a random effect. Failing that you'll probably want to group them in some way. 2. The plots are hard to compare because they're not really plotting the same things and what they "should" look like if everything is okay is slightly different. For the second plot, residuals vs log(fitted) would be more similar to the first, but still not perfectly comparable.

Comment: Hi Glen! Thanks for your reply :) I've just ran the second plot again with log(fitted) which works a treat - no real correlation in residuals. I'll update the question with the new plot after work and I'll also take a look at some way i can use R.E.! thanks again mate